# QR Factorization for the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

For this matrix:
  \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 25 \\
    0 & 0  \\
    3 & -25
  \end{bmatrix}
Solution:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac45 & \frac35 \\
    0 & 0  \\
    \frac35 & -\frac45
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}              
    5 & 5 \\
    0 & 35
  \end{bmatrix}\,\,\,$$
Unsure how they got to this solution, could some help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $QR$ factorization, the columns of $Q$ are orthogonal unit vectors that span the column space of $A$. Let the columns of A be $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2$, and let the columns of $Q$ be $\mathbf{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$ To find $\mathbf{q}_1$ and $\mathbf{q}_2$, we use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/orthonormal-basis/v/linear-algebra-the-gram-schmidt-process), as follows:
$$\mathbf{q}_1=\frac{\mathbf{a}_1}{\Vert{\mathbf{a}_1}\Vert}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4^2+0^2+3^2}}\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}\\0\\\frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{q}_2=\frac{\mathbf{b}}{\Vert{\mathbf{b}}\Vert},\,\text{where}\;\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a}_2-(\mathbf{q}_1\cdot\mathbf{a}_2)\mathbf{q}_1$$
$$\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}25\\0\\-25\end{bmatrix}-\Biggl(\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}\\0\\\frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}25\\0\\-25\end{bmatrix}\Biggr)\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}\\0\\\frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}25\\0\\-25\end{bmatrix}-5\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}\\0\\\frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}21\\0\\-28\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{q}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{21^2+(-28)^2}}\begin{bmatrix}21\\0  \\-28\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{35}\begin{bmatrix}21\\0  \\-28\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{5}\\0\\{-\frac{4}{5}}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\text{Therefore,}\;Q=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}&\frac{3}{5}\\0&0\\\frac{3}{5}&{-\frac{4}{5}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, on to $R$. Once you've found $Q$, $R$ is surprisingly easy to calculate:
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}\Vert{\mathbf{a}_1}\Vert&\mathbf{q}_1\cdot\mathbf{a}_2\\0&\Vert{\mathbf{b}}\Vert\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5&5\\0&35\end{bmatrix}$$
We've already calculated all the entries of $R$, so it's just a matter of going back in the problem and finding them. And there you have it: $$A=QR=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}&\frac{3}{5}\\0&0\\\frac{3}{5}&{-\frac{4}{5}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5&5\\0&35\end{bmatrix}$$